# How do I make a loot table in Minecraft give one of several items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

How do I make a loot table in Minecraft give me one of several items? I'm setting up a data pack where every player gets a random item every ten seconds, and want it to be less resource-intensive. I want it to drop one random item every time.

Comment: I'm no loot table expert, but don't you just need multiple entries? Then you can set their probabilities with `weight`, but maybe you don't even need to do that in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use multiple entries in a pool. For example, if you wanted it to give stone or dirt, you would use this:

```
{
  "type": "see below",
  "pools": [{
    "rolls": 1,
    "entries": [
      {
        "type": "item",
        "name": "stone"
      },
      {
        "type": "item",
        "name": "dirt"
      },
    ]
  }]
}
```

For `type`, refer to this from [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table):

> **type**: Optional type of the loot table. Must be one of `empty` if the loot table does not generate any loot, `entity` for loot an entity drops, `block` for loot a block drops, `chest` for a treasure chest, `fishing` for a fishing loot table, `advancement_reward` if it's used as a reward for an advancement or `generic` if none of the above apply.

---

See [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Loot_table) for more information.